# Console keymapping

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, hardware, acpi, thinkpad

I have installed Arch Linux on my Thinkpad W530, and none of the `Fn-Fx` keys or the volume buttons work. However, they do work **before** I have booted into Arch at the Grub menu. (I can change the brightness, and the volume mute button has an LED that goes on/off)

I also have Ubuntu installed prior, and was wondering if I could somehow copy over the keymappings for use in my Arch install. First, I booted into Ubuntu, and then stopped `lightdm`, `gnome`, `acpi`, and `thinkpad_acpi`. Yet, the Fn-keys and volume buttons still work.

Where and/or how does the OS know how to handle the Fn-keys and volume buttons? According to this [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Hotkeys/Architecture), the kernel looks for the key codes in `/usr/include/linux/input.h` But in Arch, I found the same key codes in `/usr/uapi/linux/input-event-codes.h`. So, why don't the keys work in Arch?

And how do they work before I have even booted into an OS?

Comment: Late to the party, but if you're still puzzling over this, have you looked in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/inet` (and the other files in the `symbols` directory)? That's probably where it's coming from. And they work prior to booting into the OS because at that point they're likely being handled by the BIOS directly. The kernel reports that it's <whatever>, so the BIOS makes some (possibly false) assumptions about the kernel's ability to handle ACPI events on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You may just have to map them manually in Arch (I had to do something similar in one of my Debian installs). You just need to map the keys of interest. [This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xbindkeys) should be helpful.

Comment: Well, I know that's an option. But I would like the keys to function outside of X. Also, the Fn keys don't work when Ubuntu is booted into Recovery Mode. So there must be some kind of configuration, module or daemon that runs during boot. ?